# Palabras comunes orales

Tags: coloquialismos

¿Dónde encuentro palabras comunes (no regionales) que se use en español para transcribir lenguaje oral/informal, pero normalmente no se use en lenguaje escrito/formal? Por ejemplo, las palabras ingleses de este tipo incluyen "gonna", "wanna", "gotcha", "y'all", "ain't", etc.

Comment: Pasé bastante tiempo formulando una respuesta y veo que aparentemente no vale ni un respuesta de tu parte.

Answer (score 2):

El problema de los coloquialismos es que (aparte de la práctica extremadamente común de quitar la "d" en los participios acabados en "-ado": *cansao*) suelen variar rápidamente en el tiempo y en el espacio. Quizá esto es precisamente porque no se suelen escribir.

[Aquí](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Jerga_juvenil/Espa%C3%B1a) hay una lista de palabras y expresiones **bastante** coloquiales que son bastante utilizadas en España. La columna central contiene expresiones algo más neutrales. También puedes buscar [palabras etiquetadas con la propiedad "coloquial"](https://iedra.es/palabras/?q=&search_type=e&search_order=a&tag=coloquial) en el IEDRA, pero la lista es larguísima.

Si ya has visto la expresión y quieres saber lo que significa, el DLE incluye los significados de muchas expresiones coloquiales. Por ejemplo, "faltar un tornillo" está incluido en la definición de [tornillo](https://dle.rae.es/tornillo?m=form).

Como en todas las lenguas, la mejor forma de aprender lenguaje coloquial actual es conversar con nativos, o ver series/películas o escuchar canciones españolas.

Comment: No son coloquial;ismos porque esto implicaria que son palavras en si, y no lo son. Son imitaciones por escrito del inglés hablado.

Answer (score 0):

Estas palabras como wanna, gonna, gotcha son transcripciones del inglés hablado pero no son palabras sueltas en si. ***Son una imitación por escrito de como se habla.***

wanna = want to, p.ex. I wanna go = I want to go
gonna= going to, p.ex. I'm gonna go = I'm going to go
gotcha= got you, idiomatic expression: to get someone (por lo menos dos sentidos diferentes)
ain't=isn't.

Estos **usos** se oyen en frases o discursos (en el sentido lingüístico) que tienen mas amplia existencia que las palavras en si.

Para traducirlas, hay que identificar el discurso, y intentar encontrar un semejante el espanñol. Uno se pregunta: ¿ Quién habla a quién ? ¿ Dos jovenes, dos trabajadores, dos secretarias? etc. Hay veces que uno puede trasladar el mensaje con un discurso semejante y a veces es imposible.

O sea, para evitar de hacer un trabajo de índole academico aqui, es mi opinión que hay que saber el inglés hablado muy bien para poder traducir estas expresiones que siempre vienen dento de un contexto mas amplio. No existen en el vacio.

Hay otro problemita: A veces se ve en servicios de streaming como Netflix, que ponen gonna y wanna en muchas frases pero que el hecho de hacerlo es sin impacto sobre el sentido y el discurso. O sea, estoy intentando decir que casi todos los hablantes nativos de inglés **cuando hablan rápido** terminarán diciendo wanna y gonna una vez u otra.

**Conclusión**: Hay que saber el inglés hablado muy bien para poder entender como se está usando este tipo de palabra en un contexto dado porque siempre vienen acompañados de un discurso. Estas transcripciones tales como wanna y gonna no son expresiones coloquiales.

wanna o gonna no se pueden traducir en si o sueltos al español porque lingüísticamente hablando, el español no tiene nada parecido. Tiene otras cosas, pero eso, no.